# Want to extract data from one array with .reduce() using if condition not sure what am I missing

Tags: javascript

```js
const users = [{
    name: 'Samir',
    age: 27,
    favoriteBooks: [{
        title: 'The Iliad'
      },
      {
        title: 'The Brothers Karamazov'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'Angela',
    age: 33,
    favoriteBooks: [{
        title: 'Tenth of December'
      },
      {
        title: 'Cloud Atlas'
      },
      {
        title: 'One Hundred Years of Solitude'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'Beatrice',
    age: 42,
    favoriteBooks: [{
      title: 'Candide'
    }]
  }
];
let newList = users.map(type => {
  if (type.name == 'Angela') {
    return type.favoriteBooks.map(list => list.title).reduce((acc, sames) => acc.concat(sames));
  }
}, []);
console.log(newList);
```

I am expecting the result to be

```
[
 'Tenth of December', 
 'Cloud Atlas', 
 'One Hundred Years of Solitude'
];
```

but it outputs

```
[
 "undefined", 
 'Tenth of December', 
 'Cloud Atlas', 
 'One Hundred Years of Solitude', 
 "undefined
];
```

Comment: You are not returning anything when it does not map (thus returning undefined). You should probably use filter to remove the element you don't want to map

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't need `reduce` for the output you need. Just use `map`:

```js
const users = [
    {
        name: 'Samir',
        age: 27,
        favoriteBooks:[
            {title: 'The Iliad'},
            {title: 'The Brothers Karamazov'}
        ]
    },
    {
        name: 'Angela',
        age: 33,
        favoriteBooks:[
            {title: 'Tenth of December'},
            {title: 'Cloud Atlas'},
            {title: 'One Hundred Years of Solitude'}
        ]
    },
    {
        name: 'Beatrice',
        age: 42,
        favoriteBooks:[
            {title: 'Candide'}
        ]
    }
];
let res = [];
let newList = users.map( type => {
    if(type.name == 'Angela') {
        res = type.favoriteBooks.map(list => list.title);
    }
});

console.log(res);
```

You can also use `array destructuring` inside your `map` function like this,

```js
const users = [
    {
        name: 'Samir',
        age: 27,
        favoriteBooks:[
            {title: 'The Iliad'},
            {title: 'The Brothers Karamazov'}
        ]
    },
    {
        name: 'Angela',
        age: 33,
        favoriteBooks:[
            {title: 'Tenth of December'},
            {title: 'Cloud Atlas'},
            {title: 'One Hundred Years of Solitude'}
        ]
    },
    {
        name: 'Beatrice',
        age: 42,
        favoriteBooks:[
            {title: 'Candide'}
        ]
    }
];
let res = [];
let newList = users.map( type => {
    if(type.name == 'Angela') {
        res = type.favoriteBooks.map(({title}) => title);
    }
});

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to use `reduce` in this case since it can be hard to read. You can use `find` to extract the right user then just simply use `map` to create the list of book titles from property `favoriteBooks`.

```js
let users = [
    {
        name: 'Samir',
        age: 27,
        favoriteBooks:[
            {title: 'The Iliad'},
            {title: 'The Brothers Karamazov'}
        ]
    },
    {
        name: 'Angela',
        age: 33,
        favoriteBooks:[
            {title: 'Tenth of December'},
            {title: 'Cloud Atlas'},
            {title: 'One Hundred Years of Solitude'}
        ]
    },
    {
        name: 'Beatrice',
        age: 42,
        favoriteBooks:[
            {title: 'Candide'}
        ]
    }
];
let bookList = users.find(user => user.name === 'Angela').favoriteBooks.map(book => book.title);
console.log(bookList);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this with `reduce()` the `spread syntax` and `map()` to get the required result.

**DEMO**

```js
const users = [{
  name: 'Samir',
  age: 27,
  favoriteBooks: [{
    title: 'The Iliad'
  }, {
    title: 'The Brothers Karamazov'
  }]
}, {
  name: 'Angela',
  age: 33,
  favoriteBooks: [{
    title: 'Tenth of December'
  }, {
    title: 'Cloud Atlas'
  }, {
    title: 'One Hundred Years of Solitude'
  }]
}, {
  name: 'Beatrice',
  age: 42,
  favoriteBooks: [{
    title: 'Candide'
  }]
}];

let result = users.reduce((r, {name,favoriteBooks}) => name == 'Angela' ? [...r, ...favoriteBooks.map(({title}) => title)] : r, []);

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.find` function to get the `object` where `name === "Angela"`.

Then, you can use `Array.reduce` function to store the `title` of each object in the `accumulating array.`

```js
const users=[{name:'Samir',age:27,favoriteBooks:[{title:'The Iliad'},{title:'The Brothers Karamazov'}]},{name:'Angela',age:33,favoriteBooks:[{title:'Tenth of December'},{title:'Cloud Atlas'},{title:'One Hundred Years of Solitude'}]},{name:'Beatrice',age:42,favoriteBooks:[{title:'Candide'}]}];


let newList = users
              .find(user => user.name === 'Angela')
              .favoriteBooks
                .reduce((acc, {title}) => [...acc, title], []);    

console.log(newList);
```